# Order of group $G=\langle x,y\,\,|\,\,x^2=y^2=(xy)^3=1\rangle$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Find the order of group $G=\langle x,y|x^2=y^2=(xy)^3=1\rangle$. I find that $|G|=5$ but this is not possible because $|x|=2$ not divides $|G|=5$. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How did you get $|G|=5$?

Comment: There is an element of order $2$ and an element of order $3$, so we _must_ have $6\mid |G|$.

Comment: @Arthur Strictly speaking, one must check that, e.g., $xy$ is nontrivial to conclude that it has order $3$. (This is true in this case, but for a general group presentation this problem is not trivial. IIRC even the problem of determining whether a given group presentation defines the trivial group is NP-hard.)

Comment: **Hint** Using the relations we can write out an exhaustive list of the elements in the group.

Comment: Thanks I showed that the group have order 6

Comment: It is easy to see that this is a presentation of $D_6$. Just suppose that $a :=xy$.